# expression "meat and potatoes business"

Tags: expressions

I heard of the expression "meat and potatoes business", and when I was explained what it means, I was told is that it referred to a business with no fancy products, just simple products for simple clientèle. Is this a fair description of "meat and potatoes" as an activity?

Comment: It's not so much a business selling "simple" things - rather, a business that concentrates on the *core* products for its market sector (though in most cases it comes down to the same thing).

Comment: I'd always use 'bread and butter business', but it probably comes to the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Meat and potatoes* is an informal idiom for *basic*, or *unpretentious*.  Here's an entry from an [on-line dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meat-and-potatoes), and an [on-line thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/meat%20and%20potatoes).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It means that your target group are people whose needs you are able to identify and satisfy, in a way as simple and effective as a dish of meat and potatoes. The latter satisfies your hunger completely, so you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meat%E2%80%93and%E2%80%93potatoes) defines "meat-and-potatoes" as "fundamental, basic. I would say a "meat and potatoes" business concentrates on producing a basic product that is a proven seller to a wide segment of the market.  Such a business would not be one to take risks on an untried product or cater to fringe or specialty markets.